# problem with nvidia driver 535 on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, 22.04

recently I have had a problem with NVidia. I don't know why it doesn't update completely and returns me an error. Here is my console log.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up nvidia-dkms-535 (535.154.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
Removing old nvidia-535.154.05 DKMS files...
Deleting module nvidia-535.154.05 completely from the DKMS tree.
Loading new nvidia-535.154.05 DKMS files...
Building for 6.5.0-14-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 6.5.0-14-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-kernel-source-535.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-14-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/535.154.05/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-535 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-535 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-535:
 nvidia-driver-535 depends on nvidia-dkms-535 (<= 535.154.05-1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-535 is not configured yet.
 nvidia-driver-535 depends on nvidia-dkms-535 (>= 535.154.05); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-535 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-535 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-14-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda9
I: (UUID=7eaa7918-b4c0-43cf-b6b3-2f0a0fbcf343)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-535
 nvidia-driver-535
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What should I do? previously there wasn't such an update problem.

Comment: My make.log is in /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/535.154.05/6.5.0-14-generic/x86_64/log/make.log  Where did you get your Nvidia drivers?  I've had no problems running 6.5 with 535.154.05, even the 6.5 kernel update to ...15 worked.

Answer (score 1):

There is a general problem (since 2 weeks) with building nvidia drivers and kernel 6.5 (while switch to 6.2 works fine).
The only solution is to go back to older 6.2 kernel (revert 6.5 update).
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-22-04-no-display-after-nvidia-driver-installed/278855
I have the same issue and wait for official fix.

Comment: Did you also get a message in the terminal that was similar to `Package nvidia-dkms-535 is not configured yet`?

Comment: @karel yes i get that message too. and AlexanderKleinsorge I had to switch to 5.19. 6.2 didnt worked for me.

Comment: This question should be left open. I don't think it's a duplicate of another question.

Comment: did you "Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/535.154.05/build/make.log for more information." ?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this patch.

[from git](https://gist.github.com/Fjodor42/cfd29b3ffd1d1957894469f2def8f4f6)
save it as

```
/usr/src/nvidia-535.154.05/patches/buildfix_kernel_6.5.patch
```

Then

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-dkms-535
```

This allows me to build nvidia against kerneltree-6.5

```
nvidia/535.154.05, 5.15.0-92-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia/535.154.05, 6.5.0-15-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox/6.1.48, 5.15.0-92-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox/6.1.48, 6.5.0-15-generic, x86_64: installed
```